# Doubt regarding solving an integration for radial flow of matter around a star in Newtonian gravity

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, astrophysics, astronomy, integration

The spherically symmetric flow of matter around a star in Newtonian gravity is governed by the equation
$$v\frac{dv}{dr}+\frac{1}{P+\rho}\frac{dp}{dr}+\frac{1}{r^2}=0$$

The equation of state is chosen as the polytropic equation of state: $P=K\rho^\gamma=K\rho^{1+1/n}$. Usually, this equation is integrated to obtain the conserved energy of the flow.

The integration of the first term yields $v^2/2$ and the last term yields the Newtonian potential $-1/r$. But I am having trouble integrating the middle term, i.e., the integration
$$\int\frac{dp}{p+\rho}$$ for the polytropic equation of state. Can someone help me to solve the integral?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral, after substituting in the [polytropic index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio) form of pressure, is given by:
$$
\int \ dp \ \frac{ 1 }{ k \rho^{\gamma} + \rho } = \frac{ \ln{\lvert k + \rho^{1 - \gamma} \rvert} }{ 1 - \gamma }
$$